# Complex Analysis - Residue calculations using Laurent Expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I'm trying to calculate the residue of the following function:

$f(z)=e^z/(z^2-1)$

using Laurent Expansion. However, there seem to be some steps I am missing and would highly appreciate any help on that topic.
I've noticed that there are two isolated singularities (poles) at $z=1$ and $z=-1$ and I'm able to calculate the residue using the residue formula at the poles.However, I can't seem to get the Laurent Expansion part to make sense.

For instance, the residue at $z=1$ is $e/2$.

Expanding $e^z$ at $z=1$:

$e^z = e(1+(z-1)+(z-1)^2/2!+(z-1)^3/3!+...$

Now comes the part that doesn't fit: based on the following course notes:
[image]

$f(z)$ can be expressed in the following way:

$f(z) = g(z) + k_1/(z-1)$

Where g(z) is analytic and $k_1$ is supposed to be the residue. However, dividing the Laurent Expansion of $e^z$ by $1/(z^2-1)$ I get:

$e^z/(z^2-1) = e(1/(z^2-1)+1/(z+1)+(z+1)/(2!(z-1))+(z+1)^2/(3!(z-1))+...$

First of all, there is a $e/(z^2-1)$ which is not analytic. Second of all, I can't seem to locate the coefficient which is the residue.

What am I missing?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What is the name of the theorem to say that you can write $f(z)=g(z)+k_1/(z-1),$ with $g(z)$ analytic?

Comment: I wrote it down in one of my classes of functional analysis:

Comment: Do you mean $...+(z-1)^2/2!+(z-1)^3/3!...$ for the expansion at $z=1$?

Comment: I did, I see that it came out wrong. I'll fix the first post.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I don't buy it. In a general Laurent series, the residue is the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1},$ but as J. W. Tanner is getting it, you still have the rest of the negative power terms, every one of which is not analytic at the residue point.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I edited the original post with the course notes

Comment: Your note only dealt with the case of one singularity $p$.  In this case there are two singular point instead of just one, so you need to shrink your domain $\Omega$ to have only one singularity in order to apply your definition.

Comment: @user10354138 Care to elaborate? What do you mean by shrinking the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you are calculating the Laurent series correctly. Note that any Laurent series is always taken *at one point*. So, while you may (and in this case, do) have multiple singularities, you can only choose one singularity at a time about which to expand your function in a Laurent series.

Your function does, indeed, have a simple pole at $z=1,$ and therefore your equation $f(z)=g(z)+k_{-1}/(z-1)$ should work. Your residue is correct. Mathematica yields
$$\frac{e^z}{z^2-1}=\frac{e}{2(z-1)}+\frac{e}{4}+\frac{e(z-1)}{8}+\frac{e(z-1)^2}{48}+\dots$$
There are many ways you could obtain this. Here's how I would go about it:
\begin{align*}
e^z=e\cdot e^{z-1}&=e\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}, \\
\frac{1}{z+1}&=\frac{1}{z-1+2} \\
&=\frac12-\frac{z-1}{4}+\frac{(z-1)^2}{8}-\frac{(z-1)^3}{16}+\dots,\\
\frac{e^z}{z-1}&=e\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-1)^{n-1}}{n!} \\
&=\frac{e}{z-1}+e+\frac{e(z-1)}{2}+\frac{e(z-1)^2}{6}+\frac{e(z-1)^3}{24}+\dots
\end{align*}
Finally, we multiply the two series together:
\begin{align*}
\frac{e^z}{(z-1)(z+1)}&=\left(\frac{e}{z-1}+e+\frac{e(z-1)}{2}+\frac{e(z-1)^2}{6}+\frac{e(z-1)^3}{24}+\dots\right) \\
&\times\left(\frac12-\frac{z-1}{4}+\frac{(z-1)^2}{8}-\frac{(z-1)^3}{16}+\dots\right) \\
&=\frac{e}{2(z-1)}-\frac{e}{z-1}\frac{z-1}{4}+\frac{e}{2}+\dots
\end{align*}
You see what needs to be done: collect the terms of the right power together to get the final coefficients for the various powers. You'll have more and more multiplications to do as you get further out.

Comment: Fantastic, that does clarify things. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DaveA. You're very welcome!